# Publishing an endpoint on Bluemix Server

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, ibm-cloud

I am trying to publish a web service endpoint on Bluemix server. When I tried to call method as:

```
public class HelloWorldPublisher{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://myapp.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());
    }
}
```

or like:

```
public class HelloWorldPublisher{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());
        }
}
```

and try to access wsdl document, I am getting `Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /ws/hello`

By the way, I am following [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/).
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

When publishing a webservice **you should use a `http://<host>:<port>/<path>` format.**

**Example:**

```
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:80/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());
```

However, when you specify `localhost`, it's not very clear on which network adapter your webservice will be available. If your server has a LAN and Wireless network adapter it could be that your service is available on only one of those 2.

If you know on which network address the service will run, then you should replace it by a specific IP-address. **Alternatively, if you specify `0.0.0.0`, it will run on ALL network adapters.**

```
Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:80/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());
```

My suggestion is to try with the "0.0.0.0" address, and to double-check the port number.

**EDIT:**

I see there is a source of confusion here. So here follows a longer explanation. (skip this if not necessary):

These days **computers have multiple network adapters**. Some of them can be virtual, some are real physical connections. See, I have 7.
[image: My network adapters]

Most network applications these day are TCP/IP based (e.g. FTP, HTTP, E-mail, ...) **TCP/IP applications need an IP-address** and a port number to host or connect to services. Webservices are no different. You need to publish your webservice on an IP-address and a port number.

This is where things get tricky. Your computer has multiple network adapters. **So, it's very likely that your computer has multiple IP-addresses**. If you just publish your service without specifying which address it should use, then **it's possible that your webservice will only be available through one specific network adapter. And it's possible that it's the wrong one.**

For this reason **it's recommended to specify exactly on which address you want to host your service.** For example, if your prefered Local-Area-Network adapter has a fixed IP-address (e.g. 192.168.1.20) then you can publish your service on `http://192.168.1.20:80/ws/hello`. Now it's absolutely clear on which adapter you want to launch your service.

The problem is that **not all computers have a fixed IP-address. So, luckily you can also specify `http://localhost:80/ws/hello`**. In that case your webservice will also be available for other computers on your network. Except !!!! ... and this is important !!! except if your webservice was launched on the wrong network adapter. You see, because you didn't specify an exact IP-address **your computer will pick a network adapter, or multiple. But it's not always clear which one. It could be the wrong one.**

So, **this leads us to `http://0.0.0.0:80/ws/hello`** which is a special IP-address. It means that **the webservice will be available on ALL possible network adapters**. *(Please note that the IP-address should really be `0.0.0.0` exactly like written here. It's **not** to be substituted by a real IP. `0.0.0.0` is the IP you need to use. It's a special address.)*

Any more questions ? :)

Comment: Thanks, but what if I don't want to publish it on local? I mean, I need to publish it on server and share wsdl url with my clients. Is it possible and how should I assign the url for endpoint?

Comment: I added some more explanation in my post above. -- For your specific question: The endpoint `http://localhost:80/...` will *usually* also be reachable from other computers. The specified hostname is just a way to help your application server to launch the webservice for the correct network. But you should pick url `http://0.0.0.0:80/ws/hello` , this url will **always** work , because it makes your webservice available to ALL networks.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation :) I'm having this problem while pushing my service to bluemix or running on websphere server. Actually it is almost the same question but can you check [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665400/publishing-web-service-on-websphere) topic.

Answer (score 0):

Double check you are activating JAX-WS feature in server.xml file of Liberty Profile. Something like:

```
   <featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
        <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
   </featureManager>
```

You can check in [Bluemix docs](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#optionsforpushinglibertyapplications) different options to publish app into Bluemix Liberty buildpack. One is pushing config files with the app which is what you need to activate JAX-WS feature.

Hope it helps,

Chemi.

Comment: I can see jaxws-2.2 feature in Files and Logs page as you show.

Comment: And no errors in /logs/messages.log when starting the server and the app?

Comment: It cannot see the feature `[ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for jaxws-2.2`