# Publishing Web Service on WebSphere

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, wsdl, websphere, jax-ws

I am pretty new in web services. I created a simple SOAP web service with JAX-WS (RPC style) by following **[this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/)** tutorial and I want to publish my endpoint on WebSphere. I know where my app is:

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/belediye-liberty/
```

and I assigned my publish url like:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import com.ibm.cloudoe.services.HelloImp;

//Endpoint publisher
public class HelloPub{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9080/belediye-liberty/ws/hello", new HelloImp());
    }     
}
```

But I cannot access wsdl and getting an error like:

```
[WARNING ] SRVE8093W: The servlet class name is null for the servlet named [javax.ws.rs.core.Application] so the request cannot be handled.
[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /ws/hello
```

I guess I am assigning url in a wrong way. How should I do this?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0709_gawor/0709_gawor.html) tutorial istead.

See **Building and deploying the service** section of above article.

Basically you need to build and deploy your code in proper directory/folder structure on websphere server.

As per your implemenation, websphere is looking for your webservice in **belediye-liberty/ws/hello** folder, which doesn't exist yet. That's why the error.

Although, if you will run this code in Eclipse, Net beans etc. it will work.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot understand what should I do exactly. Instructions are not clear. I am not using Maven. Can you please explain what should I run for my project in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select **Deploy Webservice** option while deploy in Step1 page